# Can I put control characters in an @-quoted string?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

Ok, this question is purely out of curiosity, since I know the alernative way of doing it.
I know that I can put control characters in a 'normal' string by escaping the control character like this:

```
string myString = "abcd\nef\"gh";
```

However, *I'm thinking of the verbatim c# @ quoted string format*. I know that I can include quotes by doubling them, but what about control characters?

This doesn't work:

```
string myString = @"abcd\nef""gh";
```

It produces 2 characters where the control character should be and will effectively be the same as:

```
string myString ="abcd\\nef\"gh";
```

**Is there another way to include control characters in a verbatim @ quoted string?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters
>   are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a
>   quote-escape-sequence.

So no, there is no way to include control characters in a verbatim @-quoted string other than to include them verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found out that I can actually include a tab or newline simply by indenting or placing on a new line, like this:

```js
string myString = @"abcd
ef""gh";
```

Now the newline is included ib the string.
Tab and newline is probably the only control characters I will need.

Comment: Yes, "the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim" as stated in the MS documentation.